# JQuery script not working on divs fetched after page load

Tags: jquery, html, load

So I have the jquery code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("div.show").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

It effects the html code here:

```
<div class="post photo">
    <img src="source" />
    <div class="show">
        <div class="caption">
        Caption
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However as you scroll down the page, more `div`'s are fetched via another script (not written by me), but the above jquery script doesn't affect them.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use jQuery's `.live()` handler - http://api.jquery.com/live/

"Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

eg.

```
$("div.post.photo").live('hover', function() {
    $(this).children("div.show").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks a bunch homie.